# Sublime Text Macro Command Move to Specific Column Number

Tags: macros, command, sublimetext3

I'm trying to move to a specific column number in a Sublime Text macro command, so that I can delete everything after that point, but I can't get the `move` command to work.

I've compared the [old](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/commands) and [new](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/commands.html) versions of the unofficial documentation, and it looks like the `move` command used to have an "amount" parameter, but it hasn't been working for me. So the reason I'm writing is because I feel like there's something the docs are leaving out, but I don't know what it is, or how to even debug it in Sublime Text.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Comment Block  ///////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
```

When the caret is at the end of the phrase "Comment Block", I need to run a command that advances the caret to a specific column number. After that, I can expand the selection to the end of the line and delete, trimming the line to be equal with its counterparts.

Comment: Yeah, it's too bad finding good info on ST Plugin development is so difficult.  I am interested in this question's answer as well.  I just had to move back one character, so I did this: `self.view.run_command("move", {"by": "characters", "forward": False})`.  I guess you could loop over that kind of command as many times as you wanted to move yours... though that looping seems clunky and so unnecessary.

Comment: yeah, that's what I ended up doing :/